# useNavigate() used in Router and still displaying error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

The error displayed:

```
Uncaught Error: useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
    at invariant (index.tsx:24:1)
    at useNavigate (index.tsx:512:1)
    at Login (Login.js:13:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
```

I'am just starting a new react project and doing basic routing however an error is cause by the use of `useNavigate`, I used to the same many times and I don't know what I'm missing:

App.js:

```
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";
function App() {
  return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/' element={<Login/>} exact/>
                <Route path={"/chat/:room"} element={<Chat/>} socket={socket} exact/>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Login.js:

```
import {useNavigate} from "react-router"
function Login() {
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const [error, setError] = useState("")
    const validationSchema = yup.object({
        username: yup.string("username must be a string").required("username is required"),
        password: yup.string("password must be a string").required("password is required")
    })
    const onSubmit = async () => {
        const user = {
            username: formik.values.username,
            password: formik.values.password
        }
        const res = await api.post('/login', formik.values)
        if (res === true){
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
            navigate("chat/1");
        }
        else
            setError("username or password incorrect");
    }
    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            username: '',
            password: ''
        },
        onSubmit,
        validationSchema
    })

   ...
}
```

Comment: Can you share your imports, specifically what you are importing from `react-router-dom`? I suspect you've mixed up the importing of `BrowserRouter`. Are you using the `useNavigate` hook anywhere else in your code? Do you have a code stacktrace to go with that error?

Comment: I added the reac-router imports of App.js

Comment: how are you importing usenavigate(). please add that too

Comment: What version of react router are you using?

Comment: It says version 7.21.0

Comment: That's not a valid RRD version, try running `npm list react-router react-router-dom` from your project directory and report back the result. All the code you've shared is `react-router-dom@6` API and syntax from what I can tell.

Comment: thank you DrewReese that was the issue I changed the react-router version and it works now

Comment: Awesome. I voted to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Comment: In react router v6, there is no `exact` prop in <Route> component anymore. All the route matchings behave like 'exact' by default.